# HAXM error after upgrading Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intel-haxm

This is my first post so Hello to all. And apologies for dragging this topic up again but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have upgraded Android Studio from 1.x to 3.5.1. The HAXM has stopped working, giving:

> **Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3, requires minimum version 4**
>
> **Emulator: No accelerator found.**
>
> **Emulator: C:\Android\SDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument**

I have installed and reinstalled the Emulator and HAXM modules from the SDK manager:

[can not post image]

The CPU supports the right technologies and are enabled (it was working before the upgrade):

[can not post image]

The service is running:

[can not post image]

I have run intelhaxm-android.exe but the only option is to remove:

[can not post image]

This is the device I am trying to load:

[can not post image]

I have tried everything I have found on this forum and other sites and nothing seems to be able to fix it.

Can someone suggest anything I may have missed?

I have tried running an arm emulator but it is so slow on my machine that I'd like to get the haxm x86 working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  You have not supplied enough information about your system configuration to answer your question. Do not reply with a comment, edit your question, and provide the required information required to submit an answer.

Comment: _"Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4"_ - that's a pretty specific error message. Have you tried to upgrade HAXM?

Comment: The version I have is 7.5.2. That is the latest version, I can't upgrade to any higher.

Comment: Just add the links to those images. Other users can help you embed them to your post.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the links below.

Comment: Looks like 7.5.4 has been released. I have upgraded to that but still same error.

Comment: Not sure why but the links I posted have now been deleted.

Comment: Am still battling with this :-(